# How can I block until Dojo Deferred is resolved?

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred

I know the recommended use case for Dojo Deferreds is to use dojo.when(def) or def.then() and provide a callback for when the Deferred is resolved. However, sometimes I run into scenarious where I really need to wait for that Deferred to complete before continuing with the current thread. Here's an example (complete example at http://jsfiddle.net/DG3Ax/2/)

```
function getSomething() {
    var def = getSomeDeferred();

    def.then(function(result) {
        dojo.place("<li>def.then() = " + result + "</li>", "output");
    });

    return def.gimmeTheResultNow();
}

dojo.place("<li>getSomething() = " + getSomething() + "</li>", "output");
```

Obviously `Deferred.gimmeTheResultNow()` does not exist, but that's the functionality I'm looking for. I don't have control of the code calling getSomething(), so I can't make it handle a Deferred; it needs the real result.

I know xhrGet() has a sync parameter that I think would do the job if this were an AJAX call, but that isn't necessarily the case. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know what your deferred does, but seems like you should get rid of it. Deferreds are for non-blocking, async behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a [very helpful answer](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-can-I-block-until-Dojo-Deferred-is-resolved-tc3990036.html#a3990037) from the dojo-interest mailing list, so I thought I'd stick it here:

> Unfortunately, you can't do this in the browser.
>
> JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded. If you're sitting waiting for
>   a Deferred to resolve, then you're using that thread. This is the same
>   thread that will be needed somewhere down the line to service a call to
>   Deferred.resolve() (which, itself, would then result in a call to the
>   function that you passed to .then()).
>
> You can call xhr synchronously because the base implementation of the XHR
>   get allows you to call it synchronously. The functionality of dojo/Deferred
>   is just a wrapper around the XHR internals.